# DB2 Between Statement for Last Sunday to This Coming Saturday

Tags: sql, date, db2, between

I am curious why this does not work:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE_TIME_COLUMN BETWEEN
    current date - int((dayofweek(current date))-1)
    AND
    current date + int(7-(dayofweek(current date)))
```

When this gives me exactly what I want:

```
select current date - int((dayofweek(current date))-1) days from sysibm.sysdummy1)
select current date + int(7-(dayofweek(current date))) days from sysibm.sysdummy1)
```

The above two will yield the correct dates that I want my specific date time column to be in between. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE_TIME_COLUMN BETWEEN
current date - ((dayofweek(current date))-1) DAYS
AND
current date + (7-(dayofweek(current date))) DAYS
```

You have to signify that you are reducing DAYS from current date as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

"Does not work" is a little vague `:)`. Your first query is missing the `DAY` part to tell DB2 what part you're doing the date math on.

However, it kind of sounds like you might want to use the [`WEEK`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_week.dita) scalar function:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE WEEK(DATE_TIME_COLUMN) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE)
  AND YEAR(DATE_TIME_COLUMN) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
```