# Get previous two Sundays Date DB2

Tags: sql, date, db2

I have been looking around for an answer to this and there there seems to be a lot of different "solutions" nothing exactly is what I am looking for. I have the below query that runs great, but I need to be able to modify the date in '2021-08-15' format to select either the last Sunday or previous Sunday depending on the column. I need to be able to just run the query and get dynamic results rather than manually changing the dates each week. Is this something that is possible using for instance the current date? All my attempts yield no results:

```
SELECT 
    RMD.ISSUE_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.ISSUE_TITLE END) AS CURR_ISSUE_TITLE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.MEMBER_IMPACT END) AS CURR_MEMBER_IMPACT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-08' THEN CURRENT.MEMBER_IMPACT END) AS PREV_MEMBER_IMPACT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.ISM_STATUS END) AS CURR_ISM_STATUS,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.ISSUE_OWNER_ORG END) AS CURR_ISSUE_OWNER_ORG,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.ISSUE_OWNER END) AS CURR_ISSUE_OWNER,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.ISSUE_APPROVER END) AS CURR_ISSUE_APPROVER
FROM LOD.ISM_ISSUE_SUMMARY_HIST_WKY CURRENT INNER JOIN
     LOD.RMD_ISS_REMED_SUMMARY RMD
     ON CURRENT.ISSUE_ID = RMD.ISSUE_ID
WHERE AS_OF_DATE IN ('2021-08-08', '2021-08-15') 
GROUP BY RMD.ISSUE_ID
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-08' THEN CURRENT.MEMBER_IMPACT END) <> MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.MEMBER_IMPACT END) ;
```

As you can see I have a lot of dependencies on the dates but they are all either the most recent or previous Sunday. Any help or direction would be great, thank you for your time.

Comment: You should be able to use two [SET variable statements](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001018.html) to eliminate all the date constants.  The Stack Overflow question [DB2 Between Statement for Last Sunday to This Coming Saturday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048311/db2-between-statement-for-last-sunday-to-this-coming-saturday) should help you with the calculation.

Comment: I tried running this code but its unsuccesful I had previously looked at that post. ```select current date - int((dayofweek(current date))-1) days from sysibm.sysdummy1)
select current date + int(7-(dayofweek(current date))) days from sysibm.sysdummy1)```          DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=);rom sysibm.sysdummy1;END-OF-STATEMENT, DRIVER=3.57.110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  RMD.ISSUE_ID
, MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = t.last_sunday THEN CURRENT.ISSUE_TITLE END) AS CURR_ISSUE_TITLE
...

FROM LOD.ISM_ISSUE_SUMMARY_HIST_WKY CURRENT
JOIN LOD.RMD_ISS_REMED_SUMMARY RMD
 ON CURRENT.ISSUE_ID = RMD.ISSUE_ID

JOIN
(
  values
  (
    current date - (dayofweek_iso (current date)    ) days
  , current date - (dayofweek_iso (current date) + 7) days
  )
) t (last_sunday, prev_sunday)
ON AS_OF_DATE IN (t.last_sunday, t.prev_sunday)

GROUP BY RMD.ISSUE_ID
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = t.prev_sunday THEN CURRENT.MEMBER_IMPACT END) <> MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = t.last_sunday THEN CURRENT.MEMBER_IMPACT END) ;
```

Refer to [Date operations and durations](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=expressions-datetime-operations-durations) and [DAYOFWEEK_ISO scalar function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-dayofweek-iso).

Comment: Hello @MARKBARINSTEIN running that worked great. Might be a dumb question but I am not too savvy with DB2, this is actually my first time using DB2 but can I implement that into my query with a nested query or is that something separate I will have to do for each date reference.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please, check it.